# Sharing an instance of OkHttpClient between apps

Tags: android, okhttp, android-context

According to https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/

OkHttpClient instance should be shared across http calls. So should I add it to a custom application context? Or should I add it to a forever running service?

All of my activities and services will need to make http calls at some points in their lives.

Thanks

Comment: Use Singleton pattern across the application. Or, easier solutions is using DI tools, such as Dagger2 or KOIN.

Answer (score 0):

I think once you are use final on declare ok-http-instance and use singleton on create it and for example retrofit instance.

you will get only one instance shared on all you app components.